# Is this possible in C++? toString(ClassName* class)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'd like to use toString with class argument, but for some reason there is an error.
The code is:

**Animal.h**

```
#include "Treatment.h"
#include "jdate.h"
#include <vector>

class Animal{
protected:
    int id;
    double weight;
    int yy;
    int mm;
    int dd;
    double accDose;
    char sex;
    vector<Treatment*> treatArray;
public:
    Animal();
    Animal(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, char newsex, vector<Treatment*> treatArray);
    ~Animal();
};
```

**Treatment.h**

```
#ifndef TRE_H
#define TRE_H
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "jdate.h"
#include "Animal.h"
#include "Cattle.h"
#include "Sheep.h"

class Treatment{
private:
    int id;
    jdate dayTreated;
    double dose;
public:
    Treatment(int id,jdate dayTreated, double dose);
    Treatment();
    ~Treatment();
    string toString(Animal* a);
};
#endif
```

**Treatment.cpp**

```
#include "Treatment.h"

using namespace std;

Treatment::Treatment(int newid,jdate newdayTreated, double newdose){
    id=newid;
    dayTreated = newdayTreated;
    dose = newdose;
}

Treatment::Treatment(){
    id=0;
    dose=0;
}
Treatment::~Treatment(){}

string Treatment::toString(Animal* a)
{
    string aa;
    return aa;
}
```

toString is in Treatment class. I'm not sure but I think it's because Animal has 
vector treatArray;. Does it actually matter?
Sorry that I cannot put the error messages here, because once I declare toString, for some reason tons of errors occur, such as

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'Treatment' : undeclared identifier    l:\2011-08\c++\assignment\drug management\drug management\animal.h  30  1   Drug Management
```

Comment: In the definition of `Treatment::toString`, you are defining string aa and returning it without assigning it any value. Do you mean to do that or is it an oversight?

Comment: Having header files include each other is not a good idea. It's usually indicative of extremely poor design, and even if you really want to do it, it has to be handled very carefully. In your case, it's totally unnecessary. In fact, neither of your header files has to include the other. You can get by (and should get by) with a forward declaration in both of them.

Comment: @Onmifarious: If this is homework, then he probably has just started learning C++ and most likely doesn't yet know what forward declarations are.

Comment: @jcarlos: Omnifarious is right, you should forward declare your classes. Basically if you use references or pointers to a class you can get by with 'forward declaring' it. This in your case would be 'class Treatment; class Animal { /*...*/ };' and similar to Treatment class.  The reason is that the compiler doesn't need to know the size of the object you are creating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Animal.h
// #include "Treatment.h"   remove this

class Treatmemt;    // forward declaration

class Animal
{
    ...
};
```

In your version, Treatment.h and Animal.h include each other. You need to resolve this circular dependency using forward declaration. In .cpp files, include all necessary h-files.

Answer (score 2):

You include Animal.h in Treatment.h before the class `Treatment` is defined, that's why you're getting the error.

Use forward declaration to solve this:

In Animal.h add line

```
class Treatment;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not used `std` namespace in both header files.

So, use `std::string` instead of `string`. Because `string` is defined in `std` namespace.

Simillarly use `std::vector` instead of `vector`.

Comment: Is this relevant to the Question?

Comment: @Als: I'm talking about header files.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. First of all, `Animal.h` should have an include guard as `Treatment.h` has:

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

// Your code here

#endif
```

I'd also suggest that you give a longer name to `Treatment.h`'s guard, you'll reduce the risk of using the same name elsewhere.

Using guards will ensure that you don't have a circular inclusion. Still you do have a circular dependency because the `Treatment` class needs to know about the `Animal` class and vice versa. However, as in both cases you used pointers to the other class, the full definitions are not required and you can - should, actually - replace in both header files the inclusion of the other with a simple declaration. For instance in `Animal.h` remove

```
#include "Treatment.h"
```

and add

```
class Treatment;
```

Both `Treatment.cpp` and `Animal.cpp` must include both `Treatment.h` and `Animal.h`.